# Understanding how to pass macro arguments to a program in Stata

Tags: global-variables, local, stata

I am currently writing a short program to print the global macro variables of the current Stata session.

I cannot understand the outcome of the following piece of code:

```
macro drop _all
global glob0: all globals 

cap program drop print_globals
program define print_globals
args start_globs

    di "$glob0"
    di "`start_globs'"

end

print_globals $glob0
```

The outcome of this is:

```
S_level S_ADO S_StataMP S_StataSE S_FLAVOR S_OS S_OSDTL S_MACH
S_level
```

Why am I not passing to `start globs` the entire information contained in `glob0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `args` statement assigns only the first argument supplied to the program to a local macro; if there are other arguments they are ignored.

The essence of the matter is whether double quotes are used to bind what is supplied into one argument.

Whether you supply an argument as a global or a local is immaterial: globals and locals mentioned on the command line are evaluated **before the program even runs** and are not seen as such; only their contents are passed to the program.

Define this simpler program and run through the possibilities:

```
program showfirstarg 
    args first 
    di "`first'" 
end 

global G "A B C D E" 
local L "A B C D E" 

showfirstarg $G 
showfirstarg "$G"
showfirstarg `L' 
showfirstarg "`L'"
```

Results in turn:

```
. showfirstarg $G 
A

. showfirstarg "$G"
A B C D E

. showfirstarg `L' 
A

. showfirstarg "`L'"  
A B C D E
```

Comment: Thanks, I also modified  my answer to be in line with the correct solution.

Comment: I also suggest to highlight this in the documentation, or to a minimum to mention this, I could not find anything about it, regards

Comment: What is "this" precisely? The question brings together the `args` command, passing arguments to a program, binding by quotes and how local and global macros are handled. All documented in [U] or [P]. I'd pass suggestions about documentation directly to StataCorp; they won't usually see threads like this.

Comment: Thanks, granted that the question touches several points, I meant the core of the question (and of the answer): the fact that when using `args`, only the first element is considered (so that compound quotes might be necessary in some cases like e.g. mine). This is not explicitly stated in the documentation. Although it might seem "obvious", a simple example in the guide could be useful, in my opinion, especially because there is not much written about `args` and this appears to be a relevant piece of information.

Comment: The help itself says "args assigns the first command line argument to the local macro  macroname1, the second argument to macroname2, and so on.". If there were complicated syntax that if you only specify one name then it catches all the arguments, then **that** would need to be specified, but there is no such syntax and for good reason.  So, the point seems completely explicit to me.

Answer (score 1):

In order to print the content of the program argument as intended, one must use compound quotes:

```
print_globals `" ${glob0} "'
```

and not `print_globals ${glob0}`.

To see this, consider the following example:

```
local A "a b c d e"
global B "a b c d e"

cap program drop print_prog
program define print_prog
args loc_input
    di "print global: $B"
    di "print local: `loc_input'"
end

print_prog `A'        
print_prog `" `A' "'  // prints both A and B as initially intended
```

The confusion here is given by the fact that `B` is printed as intended without having to use compound quotes, whereas the same does not apply for the local macro `A` when it's passed as argument to the program.

In fact, as highligted in the comments below, in the latter case only the *first* element is passed as program argument (`a` in the example). 
By using compound quotes we supply `a b c d e` as a single argument and the final result is the one wanted.

Comment: This doesn't mention the main point behind `args foo` which assigns to local `foo` the *first* argument specified. If you bind in quotes then what you are supplying to the program is a single argument. If not, and in any case, then the global or local is evaluated by Stata before the program ever sees it. What matters is whether the contents of the macro are bound by quotes or not.

Comment: Differences between globals and locals are irrelevant to how `args` behaves.